# Is there a way to know other user's device type in Twilio video call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-video

We are building a P2P video call service using Twilio video. Is there a way for one user to know which device other user is using for video call so that we can change designs a bit to support that?

For eg, if one user is using Desktop and other user is on mobile, we want to notify Desktop user that the other user is on Mobile device.

Comment: In other words, is it possible to pass any metadata using Video.connect method? I tried looking it up but looks like there is no functionality right now present to enable passing metadata.

Comment: @philnash Could you help here?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot pass metadata directly in the `Video.connect` method. But there are other ways to send metadata about a video call.

##### Naming tracks

The first thing that comes to mind is that you can name the tracks that you are sending. When you create a track, or pass options to `Video.connect` to create tracks, [you can pass a name](https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/2.17.0/docs/global.html#CreateLocalTrackOptions). For example, with a v

```js
Video.createLocalVideoTrack({
  name: 'camera'
}).then(function(localTrack) {
  console.log(localTrack.name); // 'camera'
});
```

That track name will be sent with the published track and can be readable by remote participants.

##### The DataTrack API

For more involved messaging between participants, you can use [DataTrack API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/using-datatrack-api). The DataTrack is another track, like audio and video, but it can be used to send arbitrary data payloads. Check out [the docs on using the DataTrack API for more details](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/using-datatrack-api).